# Find $\lim_{x\to\infty} x(\sqrt{(x^2+1)}-\sqrt[3]{(x^3+1)})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Question : $\lim_{x\to\infty} x(\sqrt{(x^2+1)}-\sqrt[3]{(x^3+1)})$

My attempt : I simplified the problem to
$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x^3}})$ after which I am unable to proceed. I also tried to get bounds to apply sandwich theorem. But that method too didn't work. I am unable to apply conjugate as 1 term is square root and the other is cube root. I couldn't come up with inequalities as well

I searched in stack exchange but couldn't get this sum. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(1+\frac 1 {x^{a}})^{1/n}= 1+ \frac 1 {nx^{a}}+o(\frac 1 {x^{a}})$